# Django: Template composed of Templates

Tags: python, html, django

In one of my Django templates, I have a chunk of HTML which repeats at several places in the page. Is there a way I could use another template for this chunk alone and "instantiate" the template where required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read about [template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

Or you can use [template composition](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Inheritance is, generally, a better way to go.

Comment: How will inheritance help me here? I am talking about chunks of HTML withing the same page... not across the site.

Comment: Thanks. `include` looks promising. Is it possible to send a different variable/context to each `include` instance?

Comment: @Agnel: Use composition then. In general though inheritance is a better mechanism for reusing template code and I thought a more generic answer would be useful to more people. Edited to imply that generally inheritance is a better way to go.

Comment: @Agnel: I don't think you can send different contexts to the same template. If you need to do that maybe you should render the section-template in the view multiple times and pass the rendered sections to the encompassing template in the context. You will need to look into how to compile a string into HTML (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#compiling-a-string)

Comment: I just looked at the manual. I think the `cycle` and `with` tags can be used to change context.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same issue some time ago and here is what I got.

Seems like it's not really well documented, but there is quite obvious solution - insert HTML blocks in your main template and then pass the result of the other template render there.

Example:

In main template (`app/main.html`):

```
<!-- ... -->

{% autoescape on %}
  {{html}}
{% autoescape off %}

<!-- ... -->
```

In view code:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

def my_view(request, ...):
  # Do stuff...
  context = {'data': 'data'}
  t = get_template('app/partial_template.html')
  html = t.render(context=context)

  return render(request, 'app/main.html', context={'html': html, 'rest_data': 123})
```

Thus you'll get some template rendered inside another template with perfect separation of concerns (parent template doesn't know anything about child's context nor about child itself).